# Combine Multiple SELECT queries with differents conditions in the same table in one request

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to merge several resquests in only one request. All the resquests use the same table,  but they use differents conditions.

- I try to use the "UNION" Keyword to merge the request but, it don't work, because I haven't the same number of fields in each SELECT.
- I take look about the "JOIN" keyword but, I don't see with which fields that I can make the join

The aim of this request is to get the 20 results of the sum in one row to fill a table in my UI and avoid multiples request in my code behind.

Is there a way to do this ?

Here is one of my test with this request

```
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 1 THEN Nombreplis END),0) AS NbrTSAPetits, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 2 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrTSAGrands, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 3 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrRecommandes, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 4 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrChronoBAL, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepAccueil_id = 1 THEN Poids END),0) AS PoidsTotal, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepAccueil_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS PlisTheoriques FROM datas WHERE Chantier_id = 1
UNION                 
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Scenario_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrARR, 
       IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Scenario_id = 2 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrSOR, 
       IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Scenario_id = 3 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrTRT FROM datas WHERE Chantier_id = 2                                
UNION                     
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(NombrePlis),0) FROM Datas WHERE chantier_id = 3
UNION             
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 1 THEN Poids END),0) AS NbrARRNP, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 2 THEN Poids END),0) AS NbrSTNP, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 3 THEN NombreLots END),0) AS NbrARR, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 4 THEN NombreLots END),0) AS ST, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 5 THEN NombreLots END),0) AS NbrCLASS, 
      IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 6 THEN NombreLots END),0) AS NbrINDEX FROM datas WHERE Chantier_id = 4
UNION             
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Retour_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS RETPapier, 
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Retour_id = 2 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS Divers, 
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Retour_id = 3 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS DTRSA, 
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Retour_id = 4 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS Originaux FROM datas WHERE Chantier_id = 5)

WHERE caf_id = 1;
```

I need for each request to specify chantier_id

Thanks for you help !

Comment: You could try something like `IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 2 AND Chantier_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrTSAGrands, ..., IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Scenario_id = 1 AND Chantier_id = 2 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrARR, ...`.

Comment: @HannoBinder , You're right, but in my code behind, i'll need to edit the request to change multiple parameters, and it can become a big quantity of code... So I prefer only one big request to edit. About speed performance, it doesn't matter, in this application.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to have same number of columns in  all your queries. You can "fill" up columns in some of the queries with null:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM tableA
union all
SELECT d, e, null FROM tableB
```

So even if the second query only has 2 "real" columns the whole query will work.

One other thing, you might want to use union ALL instead of union. It might be unlikely, but using union will do a distinct over the different queries. So if there are identical rows from different queries they will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find this solution :

```
SELECT    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 1 AND chantier_id = 1 THEN Nombreplis END),0) AS NbrTSAPetits,       --1
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 2 AND chantier_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrTSAGrands,       --2
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 3 AND chantier_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrRecommandes,     --3 
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepPoste_id = 4  AND chantier_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrChronoBAL,      --4
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepAccueil_id = 1 AND chantier_id = 1 THEN Poids END),0) AS PoidsTotal,            --5
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN RecepAccueil_id = 1 AND chantier_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS PlisTheoriques,   --6       
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Scenario_id = 1 AND chantier_id = 2THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrARR,                --7
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Scenario_id = 2 AND chantier_id = 2 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrSOR,               --8
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Scenario_id = 3 AND chantier_id = 2 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrTRT,               --9
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN chantier_id = 3 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS NbrPlisNumerise,                          --10
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 1 AND chantier_id = 4 THEN Poids END),0) AS NbrARRNP,                  --11
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 2 AND chantier_id = 4 THEN Poids END),0) AS NbrSTNP,                   --12
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 3 AND chantier_id = 4THEN NombreLots END),0) AS NbrARR,                --13
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 4 AND chantier_id = 4THEN NombreLots END),0) AS ST,                    --14
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 5 AND chantier_id = 4THEN NombreLots END),0) AS NbrCLASS,              --15
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Reliquat_id = 6 AND chantier_id = 4THEN NombreLots END),0) AS NbrINDEX,              --16
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Retour_id = 1 THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS RETPapier,                                  --17
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Retour_id = 2 AND chantier_id = 5THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS Divers,                  --18
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Retour_id = 3 AND chantier_id = 5THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS DTRSA,                   --19
          IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Retour_id = 4 AND chantier_id = 5THEN NombrePlis END),0) AS Originaux                --20
FROM Datas WHERE caf_id = 1;
```